# Can I use several pipelines as a argument?

Tags: freebsd

I want to check the difference of two file list

one is `ls | cut -c 1-4` another is `ls | cut -c 1-4 | uniq`

does there exists any way can let me do like this `diff (ls | cut -c 1-4) (ls | cut -c 1-4 | uniq)` or anyway can let me without saving the two list command into files then check the difference of it ..

thanks

Comment: Which shell? Some of them support process substitution: `diff <(ls | cut -c 1-4) <(ls | cut -c 1-4 | uniq)`.

Comment: @manatwork c shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (tested on Linux, from bash)

```
diff <(ls | cut -c 1-4) <(ls | cut -c 1-4 | uniq)
```

or in general, lets have two commands cmd1 and cmd2 which produces some output

```
diff <(cmd1) <(cmd2)
```

Comment: That works with `ksh93` (where process substitution originated), `zsh`  and `bash` on systems that support `/dev/fd/n` (or for some shell versions, named pipes).